# Sort by distance Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of `Stop` objects each of which contain a

`@property (nonatomic)CLLocationDistance distanceFromUser;`

How can I enumerate though the array and sort them from closest to furthest? This is the code I have tried and I do not get a sorted array back.

```
NSSortDescriptor * ascendingDistance = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distanceFromUser" ascending:YES];
[_sortedStops sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ascendingDistance]];
```

Will I have to use an 'old school' sorting method to do this or does Obj-C have a feature I can use to do this easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...I do not get a sorted array back.

Assuming that your `-distanceFromUser` method works properly, you will indeed get a sorted array back. But you're not assigning that array to anything, so you'll never know.

It looks like you expect the array to be sorted in place, but `-sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` returns a new array instead. Do this:

```
NSSortDescriptor * ascendingDistance = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distanceFromUser" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [_sortedStops sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ascendingDistance]];
```

Comment: or use `sortUsingDescriptors` for a mutable array